# How ensure downloaded pdf is displayed in iframe using firefox?

Tags: java, html, http

I am finding inconsistencies when displaying a pdf in an iframe - sometimes the pdf is downloaded to file in the downloads folder.

How can I guarantee that pdf is always displayed in iframe?

For Response On server, I just `setContentType("application/pdf");`. I do not add `Content-Disposition` to header.

In order to set up firefox:

- The Adobe Acrobat Plug-in is installed.
- Under Options->Applications->Portable Document Format (PDF) what option should be chosen:
- Use Adobe Acrobat (in Firefox),
- Use Adobe Reader version (default) - this tends to leads to inconsistencies?

Does it matter if the versions of the add-in and in the Options window are different?

Answer (score 0):

There is a default PDF Viewer in FireFox 20.0 and above. Your need set `Preview In Firefox` option in `Portable Document Format`. You might need to set `in Firefox` for other `Adobe Plugin` if you have.

Don't forget to do `multipart/form-data` encoded requests.